# Cannot import components in pages react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can't import the components to the page because this error happens

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/Home.jsx 4:0-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Card' in '/home/c4p1/blog/src/pages'
```

my project structure [structure folders][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJqqK.png

my routes.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home'

function Rotas(){
   return(
               
       <BrowserRouter>
           <Route path="/" component={Home} />
       </BrowserRouter>
   );
}

export default Rotas;
```

my app.js

```
import Routes from "./routes";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my Home.js

```
import Card from './components/Card';
import Header from './components/Header';

const sections = [
    { title: 'Blog', url: '#' },
    { title: 'About', url: '#' },
    { title: 'Portifolio', url: '#' },
  ];


export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header title="C4p1" sections={sections}></Header>
            <Card/>
            <Card/>
        </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in your routes.js file. I think it should be `<BrowserRouter>
<Routes><Route/></Routes></BrowserRouter`.`
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
           <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
`

Answer (score 3):

`./components/Card` is `src/pages/components/card`
since it is relative to the document's current directory

You should change it to `../components/Card` which is `src/components/card`

`../` will navigate to parent directory which is `src` in your case

Answer (score 0):

You're looking into the same directory by doing `"./"`.

`"./"` this means to look up at the same directory(pwd) and to look up at one level up you have to do "../".

For example:
[image]

Let's say I want to import file5.js into file4.js. I would do something like this

```
import file5 from "./file5.js"
```

and let's say I need to import file3.js into file1.js. I'll do this

```
import file3 from "../folder2/folder5/file3.js"
```

In your case, you need to go back one level up to access the components folder from pages

```
import Card from "../components/Card.jsx
```